# Why do HOM measurements use a different definition of visibility?

Tags: optics, quantum-optics

According to wikipedia (and any standard textbook), [visiblity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interferometric_visibility) is defined as $\frac{\text{max - min}}{\text{max+ min}}$

But there are quite a few papers ([here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00080), and [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms3386) for example) that exclude the minimum in the denominator, seen here. What is the motivation for this?

Comment: As written your definition is identically $1$ so presumably there’s a typo somewhere.

Comment: I fixed it, thank you. You can find the corrected definition in the wikipedia article I linked.

Comment: Please don't link to arxive pdfs but rather the abstracts - it can be quite a nuisance if one just quickly wants to check what paper it is (say over a slow connection).

Comment: My guess is that what one is interested in is deviation of a signal (here the HOM dip) from the average.  In the HOM case, this is indeed (max-min)/max, up to a factor of 2 or so; while for say an oscillating signal it is (max-min)/(max+min).  Just a guess, though.  Also note that it doesn't really matter as long as you say what quantity you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably misleading to refer to the quantity given by
$$ V=\frac{P_{max}-P_{min}}{P_{max}} $$
as the visibility. However, it is defined in this way, because one wants to know the penetration of the dip as a fraction of the maximum. As such it give one information about how much uncorrelated photons are observed, whoch fills in the dip.

Having said that, usually it is not actually the maximum that is used in these calculations. The reason is that the dip has the shape of an inverted sinc-function. It has oscillations on the sides making the maximum larger than the nominal value for uncorrelated photons. So the maximum could be misleading. Instead, one may use a value far away from the dip in the place of the maximum.